# Issue with DepthAI demo

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, openvino, luxonis

I am currently running through the demo detailed in this link: https://docs.luxonis.com/en/latest/pages/tutorials/pretrained_openvino/

Some demos work, such as the default model. However, when I try to run other models, such as "age-gender-recognition-retail-0013", they do not seem to be working properly. When I run this model, the camera works and I can see the live video, however there is no data processing being done and I can not see any information about my age/gender. What can/should I do about this?

Originally when I first had this bug I was running my code in an anaconda environment. Then I deactivated the environment and re-cloned depthai to see if that would fix the issue. This did not work. I also tried to basics (restarting my computer, closing and re-opening terminal, disconnecting and reconnecting the camera, etc).

For context, I am running macOS Big Sur Version 11.4 on an intel based Macbook Pro, using Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

The age-gender-recognition-retail-0013 model is not listed in [DepthAI Github repository](https://github.com/luxonis/depthai/tree/main/resources/nn), as such it might not be supported. You can post this question at the DepthAI [Community forum](https://discord.com/invite/EPsZHkg9Nx), or [Discussion forum](https://discuss.luxonis.com/). For your information, DepthAI is not a part of OpenVINO Toolkit.